# Creating array from instance variables of a class

Tags: java, arrays, variables, instance-variables

I have to create an array from teh instance variables of a class (the values, not the names). Currently my code simply uses getters for each variable but with 14 variables this is unsightly and not exactly code efficient. Is there any other way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Doh! My apologies, Java

Comment: i dont get the question, can you please post the code?

Comment: If the instance fields are completely unrelated – e.g. age, height, numberOfSiblings, examScore – then the code would be more readable if you kept them as separate fields each with its own getter. But if they truly are related – e.g. a sequence of test scores for the last 20 tests done – then you should have a getter that takes an index argument: `getScore(int index)`.

Comment: Thank you jwanger. I decided to go an easier route and just make an array of the variable names! It's less flexible and the code has to be modified directly if more variables have to be added but it's just an exercise! Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method inside the class, like getInstanceVaribles, that returns an array with the instance variable values. So then you can use `this.variable_names` when assigning the values of the array instead of making and using getter methods, and this will add a layer of abstraction to your code, and simply the client code.

Comment: Jwanger I thought about doing that but my brain was frazzled and for some reason I thought it wouldn't work. I can't think why now lol

Comment: You should be able to do it. Even if the data types are different for the indivudual attributes. Just declare the array as  `Object[] if thats the case

Comment: Remember the reason now. If I create an array inside the class it's the same amount of code as me creating an array outside the class with getters right?

Comment: Correct if me if I am wrong but, it should be less because you would need to have a heading for the getter method, the return statement for the method, and then you use it somewhere else by calling it. Which at minimum is 3 lines of code when you can use this. which is one line of code.

Comment: So did that end up working for you? Or do you have any follow up's? @Hywel Griffiths

Comment: Thank you jwanger. I decided to go an easier route and just make an array of the variable names! It's less flexible and the code has to be modified directly if more variables have to be added but it's just an exercise! Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Basically to get the fields defined in the class by reflection and get the value of the field for that object.

Example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Model m = new Model(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600);
        Field[] fields = m.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Object[] data = new Object[fields.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!field.isAccessible()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
            Object o = field.get(m);
            data[i] = o;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}


class Model {
    private int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    public Model(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

JDK: `1.8`